# Carto legends are missing when embedded?

Tags: carto, legend

I've been using CartoDB at work to create maps and then embed them on our website. This has been working fine until recently, when the platform switched to Carto Builder.

Now, when embedding maps on the website, the maps are missing their legend although I created them and can see them on Carto. I also made sure to check that the legends box is ticked on the Map Options bar.

Why are the embedded maps missing the legend?

Comment: Could you please share the link and the website where the map is embedded? Two hypothesis, one: map created with Editor opened with BUILDER. Or two: the iframe is too small and the legend disappears by default.

Comment: I seem to have a combination of these issues: If I open a map in Carto Builder, the legend on the respective website map is gone. Creating new maps with Carto Builder and then embedding them, leaves me with missing legends as well. However, after I changed the iframe width/height on these newly created maps, the legends came back.

Answer (score 1):

The legends in the CARTO Builder are very big and they disappear from the embed maps when the width of the screen is less than 600px.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure that a legend does appear on mobile? This would seem like a pretty basic thing

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible in Builder